# Changing the default camera in Google Chrome - No effect

Tags: google-chrome, camera

I changed the default camera in Google Chrome and I restarted the browser. As you can see the camera I set is OBS Virtual Camera:

[image]

The problem is that, when I try to use Video Recorder (an App in Google Drive), at the top right the default camera is still the PC camera and the app use that instead of OBS Virtual Camera:

[image]

How can I change the camera also in the above pop-up?

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: in the Device Manager disable all the webcams you are not interested in.